# Convert Mono<Mono<Something>> to Mono<Something>

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm looking for a way to convert

```
Mono<Mono<Something>>
```

to

```
Mono<Something>
```

What is the way to do this without using `block()` or `subscribe()`

Comment: how did you get Mono<Mono<T>>? Probably somewhere in the flow you are using `map` instead of `flatMap`

Comment: You're right Alex..but what is the logic behind this? Does 'map' introduce another mono?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
Mono<Mono<Something>> input;//TODO set to something 
Mono<Something> flattened = input.flatMap(Function.identity());
```

`flatMap` first maps the element in the `Mono` to a `Mono` so you have a `Mono<Mono<T>>` using a `Function` (in your case a function that just returns the elements i.e. keeps it as-is as you already have a `Mono<Mono<T>>`) and then flattens it to a single `Mono<T>`.

`Function.identity()` is equivalent to `elem -> elem`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Mono<Mono> doesn't really make sense, and most probably is the result of incorrect code. You can obtain it by wrapping a `Mono` by another `Mono`, for example, by using `Mono.just`.

Consider the following code

**Incorrect**

```
Mono<Mono<Integer>> flow = Mono.just(1)
    .map(value -> Mono.just(value++))
```

**Correct**

```
Mono<Integer> flow = Mono.just(1)
    .map(value -> value++)
```

If you have control over the code, it's better to find the root cause and fix the issue. Otherwise, you can use a solution proposed by @dan1st and apply `.flatMap(Function.identity())`.